# Why doesn't my else statement work when I put only 2 inputs?

Tags: java, string, accounting

Ok so I'm working on my accounting application and heres what i got so far:

```
public class Accounting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userinput = input.nextLine();

            String[] parts = userinput.split(" ");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            String part3 = parts[2];

            int a = Integer.parseInt(part1);
            float r = Float.parseFloat(part2);
            int t = Integer.parseInt(part3);
            double Total = a*Math.pow(1.0+(r/100.0), t);

            String[] result = userinput.split(" ");
            if (result.length == 3) { 
                System.out.println(Total);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Usage: a r t (a is the amount, r is the rate, and t is the time)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made it so that if the user puts more than 3 inputs, it will give a usage prompt. However, when I put in 2 inputs, I get an error instead of the usage prompt, even though 2 is not equal to 3.

Heres the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at Accounting.main(Accounting.java:15)

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** My issue here isn't that the part of the array is not there because there is only two inputs, but that it won't give the usage prompt.

Comment: I assume the answers so far are correct, but in the future it would help if you included the error message.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because you try to access part of an array that doesn't exist:

`String part3 = parts[2];`

Where `parts.length == 2`

I assume you get an index out of bounds error?

Answer (score 2):

When you have only 2 inputs the range of your parts array is [0..1], thus when you try to access parts[2] here:

```
   String part3 = parts[2];
```

An error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

*"My issue here isn't that the part of the array is not there because there is only two inputs, but that it won't give the usage prompt."*

No, you're wrong. The point is that you need to check the length of the array **before** using it with your assumed length. This is a simple rearrangement that should work correctly (besides that presumably you're missing a few things as well like an exit condition and trying for NumberFormatException from the parsing):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){
    String userinput = input.nextLine();

    String[] parts = userinput.split(" ");

    // check first
    if (parts.length != 3){
        System.out.println(
            "Usage: a r t (a is the amount, r is the rate, and t is the time)"
        );
        continue; // skip the computation if the input is wrong
    }

    String part1 = parts[0]; // these lines WILL throw an error
    String part2 = parts[1]; // if you attempt to access elements
    String part3 = parts[2]; // of the array that do not exist

    int a = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    float r = Float.parseFloat(part2);
    int t = Integer.parseInt(part3);
    double total = a*Math.pow(1.0+(r/100.0), t);

    System.out.println(total);
}
```